# Get battery level of Wacom tablet?

Tags: wacom, graphics-tablet

I've been playing about with a Wacom Intuous drawing tablet lately using the wireless kit, and everything I want to do works just fine, but I have no way of checking the battery level. According to Wacom's documentation, there is no indication from the device itself, even when the battery is low. To check, Wacom's software must be used, which I assume will only work under Windows.

Comment: Maybe totally unrelated, but out of the box the power level dialog on my KDE lists both the level of the batteries in my laptop, but also the level of the batteries in my Logitech mouse... Did you check the standard power level indicators when the table is on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In principle, you should be able to do it in a terminal emulator with `upower`. Firstly, find the device name:

```
[romano:~] % upower -e
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/tablet_wacom_battery_1
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
```

and then, inquire:

```
[romano:~] % upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/tablet_wacom_battery_1
  native-path:          wacom_battery_1
  model:                Wacom Intuos PT S (WL)
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Wed 27 Feb 2019 18:10:02 CET (77 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  tablet
    warning-level:       none
    percentage:          100%
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charged-symbolic'
```

...I can confirm it's working (be aware that the name of the battery can change):

```
[romano:~] % upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/tablet_wacom_battery_0
  native-path:          wacom_battery_0
  model:                Wacom Intuos PT S (WL)
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Tue 12 Mar 2019 10:47:18 CET (47 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  tablet
    warning-level:       none
    percentage:          45%
    icon-name:          'battery-good-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1552384038  45.000  discharging
    1552384037  64.000  discharging
    1552383975  0.000   unknown
  History (rate):
    1552383975  0.000   unknown
```